# ansible extrct uid form ldap_search and use to make ldap filter

Tags: regex, ansible, ldap

hello i obtain this result after an ldpa_search

```
 {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "results": [
            {    
                "cn": "workagfa",
                "uniquemember": [
                    "uid=gp2513,ou=user,O=agfa,C=com",
                    "uid=as2179,ou=user,O=agfa,C=com",
                    "uid=mh1382,ou=user,O=agfa,C=com",
                     .......
```

ther is a way to extract only the uid

for example use a regex

```
uid=([-\d]*[^\;])
```

and a create a fact like this

```
((uid=gp2513),(uid=as2179),(uid=mh1382))
```

this is is used to add a filter to a ldap query

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
  tasks:
    - name: something
      : get the extract of ldap
      register: output

    - name: extract uids
      set_fact:
        uids: "{{ uids | default([]) + [item.split(',')[0]] }}"
      loop: "{{ ouput.results.0.uniquemember.0 }}"

    - name: display uids
      debug:
        var: uids
```

Comment: i receive  ``` "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: uid=gp2513,ou=user,O=agfa,C=com. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup." ```

Comment: i have answered following your structure displayed, i have tested and its ok . that's means your structure is different you are showing

Comment: yes sorry i use now ldap_groups.results.0.uniquemember to loop and works. many thanks